# Use npm from Bazel

Tags: npm, bazel

From Bazel I want to run some `npm` commands to `install` node modules,
and to `run` some webpack commands.

I have created a *genrule* to run the correct commands, but this seems to run in a sandbox without the `npm` command.

I found https://github.com/redfin/npm-bazel but am unsure if this does what I want.
In this they seem to add a `new_http_archive` for node, and I'm thinking whether doing this and then passing it to my commands via the `tools` argument in genrule is the correct approach?

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/pubref/rules_node and https://github.com/yohcop/bazel_webpack/tree/master/webpack.

Comment: Or https://github.com/corstijank/bazel_webpack.

Comment: Also the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550809/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-to-copy-folder-and-perform-npm-install seems sort-of similar - looks like one needs in-depth knowledge about how bazel rules work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the project you link to is an npm module to **generate** a bazel workspace (and maybe build files).
I think you want the other direction to depend on npm modules.
AFAIK there isn't yet rules_npm but there is some [basic support](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_typescript/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=npm&type=) in rules_typescript.
I haven't yet used it (we're migrating JVM code before JS code) but I suggest you try to poke there and see if it's usable for you even without the typescript part.
The above link shows some commits, issues and very basic code pointers for npm.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**
[rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) has been released and it has built in support for npm.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!

Comment: @O.O. Sure thing. If it does don't forget to accept it as the answer

Comment: Now a nodejs version has been added in [rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs), which I used instead!

Comment: I think the same people maintain both repos. I've updated the answer.